How to change Katakana conversion in Google Japanese IME on Windows
I have custom Romaji table entries in the Google Japanese IME for Windows (symbols such as wu, yi, ye /、/、/ and small forms of various kana like of を/ゐ/ゑ). However, there is no option to change which symbol they convert to in Katakana mode; they just use the same symbol as in Hiragana mode, so if I type e.g. "kwi-nn" in Hiragana I will get くーん, but in Katakana I get クーン rather than クーン with a small  as I would hope. And, in Katakana it will give  instead of . I can work around this by adding specific key combinations for Katakana forms (e.g. "ywe" for  and "xwyo" for ) but this isn't a good permanent solution for me, it's quite clunky. I tried finding where the conversion "rules" for this might be stored so I could try to edit them, but I couldn't find anything.
